# Setear un objeto MediaPlayer como tono AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

estoy en el desarrollo de una aplicacion la cual tiene 4 objetos `MediaPlayer` cargados y son reproducibles, muy parecido a una botonera

Quiero poder setearlos como tono de llamada, notificaciones o mensaje y no encuentro por ningun lado como hacerlo.

desde ya gracias por su tiempo :), perdonen si no formule muy bien la pregunta, soy bastante nuevo en stackoverflow.

Los objetos son cargados asi, los agrego a una carpeta raw previamente y luego.

```
sonido1 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.SonidoRandom);
```

Comment: Indague sobre el tema y tal vez esto te de una pista https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271777/how-to-set-ringtone-in-android-from-my-activity

Comment: @bercklyn Carlosviza parece bueno pero , una pregunta como se la ruta exacta del audio ? . perdona si suena muy noob la pregunta esque se que tecnicamente tiene que estar en el celular porque viene con mi aplicacion pero , el user no puede almacenar la app tanto en microSD como en el telefono ?

Comment: ¿Como cargas tus objetos medias player? Deberías coger su dirección para poder trabajar con esas mismas direcciones o en su defecto con una carpeta la cual crees en donde almacenaras   los archivos elegidos para que se vuelvan los nuevos tonos.

Comment: @bercklyn Carlosviza Los agrego a una carpeta raw .                 
     sonido1 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.SonidoRandom);

Comment: Prueba  con esa dirección replicar el ejemplo que te comparti pero solo la ultima parte ya que ahi lo que hace es guardar un archivo nuevo, en tu caso seria obtener el media y setear el valor default

Comment: @bercklyn Carlosviza  Gracias bro, Voy a probar :)

Comment: @WhySoBizarreCode no entiendo lo que deseas realizar, ¿quieres 4 botones para reproducir los cuatro audios?

Comment: @Jorgesys no, eso ya lo hice , lo que quiero es poder ponerlos como rigntone con otro boton o como sonido de notificaciones digamos o algo asi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien, despues de unos dias de investigacion y pruebas por fin lo consigo. dejo el codigo ...

```js
btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                if(rt1.isChecked() == true){ //aca comparo con dos radio buttons si quiero un ringtone o un sonido de notificacion

                    ways="/media/audio/ringtones/";

                }else if(rt2.isChecked() == true) {

                    ways="/media/audio/notifications/";

                }else{
                    ways="/media/audio/ringtones/";
                }



                pathi=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ ways; //aca tomo el directorio de sd mas el path de los ringtones o sonidos de notificaciones

                boolean exists = (new File(pathi)).exists();
                if (!exists) {
                    new File(pathi).mkdirs();
                } //si no existe el direct lo creo

                File newSoundFile = new File(pathi, "sound.mp3");//creo el archivo de sonido
                Uri mUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.harrypotter.harrysound/"+R.raw.sound); //lo cargo con mi mp3 en el raw
                ContentResolver mCr = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
                AssetFileDescriptor soundFile;




                try {
                    soundFile= mCr.openAssetFileDescriptor(mUri, "r");
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    soundFile=null;
                }

                try {
                    byte[] readData = new byte[1024];
                    FileInputStream fis = soundFile.createInputStream();
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newSoundFile);
                    int i = fis.read(readData);

                    while (i != -1) {
                        fos.write(readData, 0, i);
                        i = fis.read(readData);
                    }

                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException io) {
                }



                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath()); //indico la ruta del archivo
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "soundharrybtn");
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, newSoundFile.length());
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "HarrypotterMagia");


                if(rt1.isChecked() == true){
                    types=RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE;
                    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
                    tipito="Ringtone";

                }if(rt2.isChecked() == true){

                    types=RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION;
                    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
                    tipito="Sonido de notificacion";

                }if(rt1.isChecked() == true || rt2.isChecked() == true){

                    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    Uri newUri = mCr.insert(uri, values);

                    try {
                        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(tuneActivity.this, types, newUri);
                        Toast.makeText (tuneActivity.this,tipito+" puesto con exito",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //con ringtone manager set, pongo el audio como predeterminado

                    } catch (Throwable t) {

                        Toast.makeText (tuneActivity.this,"No se pudo establecer el ringtone puesto con exito",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                }else{

                    Toast.makeText (tuneActivity.this,"No selecciono Sonido de notificacion ni Ringtone ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }



            }
        });
```

```
   ## Extras##
```

Esta funcionando todo pero este bloque Aun no me queda muy claro si alguien me lo puede explicar mejor. ;)

```
    try {
                soundFile= mCr.openAssetFileDescriptor(mUri, "r");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                soundFile=null;
            }

            try {
                byte[] readData = new byte[1024];
                FileInputStream fis = soundFile.createInputStream();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newSoundFile);
                int i = fis.read(readData);

                while (i != -1) {
                    fos.write(readData, 0, i);
                    i = fis.read(readData);
                }
```

espero el codigo les funcione y les haya ayudado